# NZEC error in python code

Tags: python

MY code is working perfectly fine on my machine but it gives M+NZEC erro when compiled by spoj.
Here is the link to my ques:
http://www.spoj.com/problems/CPRIME/

Here is my code:

```
def smallPrimes(n):
    """Given an integer n, compute a list of the primes <= n"""
    if n <= 1:
        return []
    sieve = range(3, n+1, 2)
    top = len(sieve)
    for si in sieve:
        if si:
             bottom = (si*si - 3)//2
             if bottom >= top:
                 break
             sieve[bottom::si] = [0] * -((bottom-top)//si)

    return [2]+filter(None, sieve)

from math import *
import sys
def main():
    flag=True
    while(flag==True):
        x=input()
        if(x==0):
            flag=False
            return 0
        z=x/log(x)
        v=len(smallPrimes(x))
        print round((abs(v-z)*100/(v)),1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SPOJ the NZEC error is raised when an exception occurs in the Python script execution. 
In your case as the problem in input is well specified and terminates on a zero, so it can't be because of input as you take that into consideration.

The error is most likely because of usage of more memory than allowed. In your problem the memory limit is specified as 256 MB. But in your code

```
sieve = range(3, n+1, 2)
```

This line declares a list of size about n/2. When, n=10^8 it means that you will declare a list with 5*10^7 integers which with a naive approximation and ignoring all the overheads will be

```
(5*10^7)*4 bytes
 ~ 200 MB
```

Including the overheads and other memory usage for your second big list declaration

```
[0] * -((bottom-top)//si)
```

which can reach about 130 MB neglecting all the overheads, you will exceed the memory limit to just store that many integers in the list. I noticed memory usage of about 1 GB by your code on my machine. So your code crosses the memory limit on SPOJ and it raises an exception.

The best thing to do is to optimize your approach, declaring lists of the order of 10^8 is seldom needed in such questions. I can see a way in which you won't need to declare a list that big but since it's a question of an online judge, it's best to let you figure out the approach. :)

Comment: Thanks mate!! I will try to optimize it...(y)